# Why does my create_rectangle disappears after specifying these points using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to create a transparent box with a red outline between these two specified points at (614, 162) and (759, 306). However, it returns me an invisible or no box at all. But for (100, 50) and (160, 100), the box is visible.

```
import tkinter as tkr

app = tkr.Tk()

app.title("AI Cashier")

app.geometry("1366x768")

app.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")

app.config(bg = "White")

can = tkr.Canvas(app,bg = "White",highlightthickness = 0)

can.create_rectangle(100,50,160,100,outline = "red", width = 2)

can.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Could anyone explain to me because I'm still new to tkinter. Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does my create_rectangle disappears after specifying these points using tkinter?

It is because the canvas is only a couple hundred pixels wide and tall, so you are drawing outside the visible area of the canvas.

A simple fix for the code in the question is to make the canvas bigger. You can either give it an explicit width and height (eg: `can = tkr.Canvas(..., width=800, height=400)`), or force the canvas to fill the window (eg: `can.pack(fill='both', expand=True')`). In either of those cases, the image will be visible.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that. Thanks for spending time answering it anyway.